# What is Dependency attribution?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, web-deployment

**Hi Guys long time listener first time caller lol...But I am trying to learn what dependency attribution is when it comes to software development. I have seen a few references of it being similar to a works cited page and giving credit where its due. Does anyone have any examples of how to document this or just some examples? Thanks a bunch I am super lost on the topic.**

Comment: What is required for each dependency should be defined by the license it is associated with.